# How many 5 digit integers that their digits chosen from {5,2,8,8,6,6,0} satisfies "if there's 8, it's followed by 6"?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So i solved the first part of this question, that there's 588 ways for choosing 5 digit integers, but i can't solve "Find the number of integers in (i) which satisfies "if there's 8, it's followed by 6"
i tried to solve it using different cases:

Case 1) there's two 8s and two 6s => (3 * 3!)/2! - 1

Case 2) there's two 6s and 8 => 4 * 4!-3*3!

Case 3)  8 and 6 => 4!-3!

the sum was 104 but i don't think that's right, should i make another case for no 8s? or is there an easier way.

Comment: Are 8s and 6s different?

Answer (score 1):

If there is no $8$ then

Total $5$ digit distinct numbers=$\frac{5!}{2!}-\frac{4!}{2!}$=$60-12=48$

If there is one $8$, it must be followed by $6$. We treat the pair as one. Notice that $8$ can't be unit place digit.So we can place $8$ in the first $4$ positions followed by $6$.

Consider $8$ being not in the first position. Then  for each of the other three position, we have $^4P_3-^3P_2=18$(subtracting numbers starting with $0$). So total distint $5$ digit numbers containing only one $8$ and not starting with $8=18×3=54$

Now if such a number starts with $8$, then distinct numbers$=^4P_3=24$

So with one $8$, there are $54+24=78$

If there are two $8s$ , there must be two $6s$ , then the two groups of $86$ are treated together.

Consider the remaining digit to be placed at the left, middle of the two groups and at the rightmost. Now there are 2 different choices for the leftmost, 3 for the middle, and 3 for the right.So with two $8$ , total numbers$=8$

Hence total numbers $=48+78+8=134$

Answer (score 0):

Add up the ways to do it with no $8$, one $8$ or two $8$s.

If there are no $8$s you must choose $5$ components (with order) from $\{5,2,6,6,0\}$  There are $\frac {5!}2$ ways to do this but as your number can't start with $0$ we must subtract the $\frac {4!}2$ ways to start with $0$.

If there is one $8$ then you must place an $86$ in four possible locations.  the $3$ remaining slots must be filled with $\{5,2,6,0\}$ and there are $3!$ ways to do that.  but we must subtract the ways that start with $0$. If it starts with $0$  there are $3$ spots for the $86$ and $2!$ ways to do the rest.

If there are two $86$s then you must place $86,86, x$ into $3$ slots. There are $3$ places to put the one digit that *isn't* one of the $86$ and that $1$ slot can be filled with $\{5,2,0\}$ and there are $3$ ways to do that.  But there is $1$ way the first slot is a $0$ and we must omit that.

So putting it together:

$(\frac {5!}2 - \frac {4!}2) + (4*3!- 3*2!) + (3*3 - 1)$